# How to prevent execution of "sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root / " command?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, rm

After going through this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521293/an-ubuntu-command-bricked-my-sytem) I'm quite scared!

It's not that I don't want to use `sudo rm` command, but I want to inhibit the execution of the `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` command.
If this command can ruin a motherboard, **Why does it even exist ?** or **Why should it even exist ?**

Comment: because it's your system and you can break it if you want to

Comment: Linux does not usually limit what an administrator can do; hiding and disabling features from power users because they might be destructive in the wrong hands is not the Linux way. Even Windows allows you to delete system directories or format the hard drive *if that's what you really wan to do!* If it's any reassurance, you cannot run that command without being prompted for your password; this gives you a chance to make sure it's what you want to run.

Comment: The command itself does not brick your computer, it simply deletes all files in the file system tree. The problem is not this command, but that parts of the EFI system are mounted writeable by `systemd` and that some EFI implementations are not following the standard and can not handle this.

Comment: Why be so scared of it? It needs the `--no-preserve-root` option, which you can't just type in by accident, and it needs your password, so someone else can't just walk up to your computer and type it. It might seem scary, but you can just as easily throw your computer off the balcony of a third-story apartment **if you want to**. If you don't want to, just don't throw it off the balcony; problem solved.

Comment: Yeah ! Actually true :D

Comment: "Why does it even exist" Because Linux does not offer many idiot-proof guards — this is a *strength* — if I want to change something big, Windows or OS X is like "No no no you don't want that" but Linux is "OK, If you say so." It lets *me* choose how I run my system. It does what I tell it to do. I recommend reading [Chapter 12](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bharadwaj-raju/5919a62c260d0c8c956c423eac8c0e39/raw/4e19e4626d73a5f838b5b49bd1dded435b4d5791/Chapter_12) of "In the beginning there was the command line".

Comment: Nice story :D "But I never blamed the Hole Hawg; I blamed myself. " so linux users must be careful enough you say !

Comment: @rohith Correct. Linux assumes you *know* exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to Security Whack-A-Mole, the game where you try to enumerate ALL the ways you can get hurt, and try to wrap each one in bubble wrap. You can never win.

Rather, learn to use Unix/Linux tools, understand what your system does, and don't run scripts (or anything) you don't understand (that comes from an untrusted-for-system-upgrades source).

Your question is equivalent to "I can shoot myself in the foot, thusly. Why don't guns not automatically deflect their aim away from me?"

Comment: lol, that joke made more sense than many explanations i read so far