# How delete a folder when certain password is entered

Tags: login, password, shredding

I want to remove a folder (or write on it by `shred`) when a specific password is entered. I don't want to use an encrypted OS like LUKS as [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977560/how-to-trigger-a-terminal-command-when-incorrect-password-entered#comment1569550_977560) says, or destroy the whole drive as lots of people say.

I have an idea. I can use 2 passwords to login to the system. 1st one is a usual password, but when I entered the second one, system logins but [runs a script as startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) like:

```
rm -rf /address/of/folder
```

or:

```
shred -u file.txt
```

Is this idea possible? (Can I use 2 passwords to login?)

Comment: I think that you confuses passwords and users. A user can have only one password. You can have two users (or more) and in the relevant users .profile add the commands you want to run.

Comment: No. Not possible. Use encfs for things like this. https://www.arg0.net/encfs

Comment: (sorry for the off) Your SU edit suggestion was pretty okay. But, it changed an other, also pretty okay solution to your version. I suggest to post it as a new answer, it is very good (I did not even know these flags), you will get some ups and we don't lose useful content.